# RecursionError on macOS with tkinter moving objects

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

I am learning with tkinter, and that involves fluid motion of shapes. That's where I am stuck now.

I get inconsistent recursion errors. The code works no problem on Windows 1O, but on my macOS it crashes.

Furthemore, if the time between recursions is ≥ 17 milliseconds, it just stops making errors and runs as intended. I've simplified the code, just to contain the one problem.

```py
from tkinter import *
master = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(bg = "gray", width = 1000, height = 800)
canvas.pack()
cara = canvas.create_line(100,100,900,100, width = 5, fill = "red")

def moveCara():
    canvas.move(cara, 0,1)
    canvas.after(16, moveCara)  # Here is the time setting, change it to 17 and the thing
                                # does not crash.
    canvas.update()

moveCara()
mainloop()
```

This code causes crash on my MacBook:

`RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded during compilation`

However, if I change the time in `canvas.after()` to 17 or greater, everything works. why is that?

Comment: Try not calling ```canvas.update()```

Comment: Also, depending on what you want to do. ```pygame``` would be a good library to use.

Comment: Try calling `canvas.update_idletasks()` instead of `canvas.update()`. The latter "can lead to unpredictable behavior or looping". See [Universal widget methods](https://web.archive.org/web/20190326025633id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line of code:

```
canvas.update()
```

You should definitely not be calling `update` inside a function called from an event handler (and running a function via `after` is considered an event handler). It's completely unnecessary to make your program work and needs to be removed.

What is happening is that your call to `after` adds some work to be done by `mainloop` after a given amount of time. When you call `update`, it performs that work if the given amount of time has elapsed, otherwise it might not do anything at all.

If your computer is slow enough, then by the time you call `update` it will be time for the next frame of your animation. That causes `moveCora` to be called again via `canvas.update()` *before the first call returns*. And that is why you get a recursion error.

I wasn't able to duplicate the problem on my machine at 16ms, but I was able to reproduce it when I moved the time to 5ms. You must have a machine that takes more than 16ms to move the line and then call `after`. When I remove the call to `canvas.update()` I am able to set the value down to 1ms without a problem.